# While running ReactiNative project index.js not found error occur

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I am new to ReactNative I am facing one issue. Please check below log for same. I am facing this issue when trying to run ReactNative project using

```
react-native run-android
```

**Error Log:**

> Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` from `D:\ReactNativeProject\testing\node_modules\react-native\scripts/.`: The module `./index` could not be found from `D:\ReactNativeProject\testing\node_modules\react-native\scripts/.`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
>         * `D:\ReactNativeProject\testing\node_modules\react-native\scripts\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
>         * `D:\ReactNativeProject\testing\node_modules\react-native\scripts\index\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
>           at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\ReactNativeProject\testing\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
>           at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (D:\ReactNativeProject\testing\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
>           at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\ReactNativeProject\testing\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:283:16)
>           at D:\ReactNativeProject\testing\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:261:42
>           at Server. (D:\ReactNativeProject\testing\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1038:41)
>           at Generator.next ()
>           at asyncGeneratorStep (D:\ReactNativeProject\testing\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:99:24)
>           at _next (D:\ReactNativeProject\testing\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:119:9)
>       ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [29/Mar/2019:05:12:54 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"

**What I have done to solve this?**

1). I tried below command as I found a solution on Github

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

2). I tried to remove the **node-module** folder and install it again but still not got success.

**React Native Version:** 0.59.2

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Goto `node_modules\react-native\scripts\launchPackager.bat`

// comment this line

```
node "%~dp0..\cli.js" start
```

Add this line

```
node "%~dp0..\cli.js" start --projectRoot ../../../
```

After that run your project root `cd android && gradlew clean` and after run `react-native run-android`

Comment: Thanks bro it works. U saved my time. I spend lots of time on this. Can u tell me why we made those changes?

Comment: @LokeshDesai I face that problem with this version 0.59.2. Please review this link for open issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23908

Comment: yes i also faced issue in 0.59.2. thanks for link. most of people able to solve that using react-native start --reset-cache but in my case it is now working. Anyway thanks for solution.

Answer (score 1):

run

```
react-native start -- --reset-cache
```

then run

`react-native run-android`

in separate command line window.

This works fine for me.

I also notice people fix it by writing some code in `node_modules\react-native\scripts\launchPackager.bat`, but writing code in node_modules isn't recommended.